# odoo: Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action

Tags: odoo-13

I am totally new to odoo, now I am learning about building modules and I am working with odoo 13, When I tried installing the school module it gives me the following error:

> File "/home/user/odoo/odoo13/odoo/fields.py", line 2338, in convert_to_cache
> raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
> odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action: 'form,189'" while parsing /home/user/odoo/odoo13/custom_addons/school/views/student_view.xml:2, near

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="student_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Students</field>
            <field name="res_model">student.student</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Student
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="school_menu" name="School"/>
        <menuitem id="school_student_menu" parent="school_menu" name="Student" action="student_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I would appreciate any help, feel free to ask for more informations if necessary in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your double quote and tag near `type` attribute:

```
<field name="help" type="html
   <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Student</p>
 </field>
```

It should be `type="html">`